# class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.String error when having a hashmap of mixed types (Long and string)

Tags: java, postgresql, hashmap, apache-camel

I have spring boot - camel application that connects to a postgre database and returms from a select query the following array:

```
[{id=1, name=JENNY, country=LB}, {id=2, name=AMIGOSCODE, country=UK}]
```

id is of type `bigint` in the database however name is of type `string`

when executing the following code:

```
@Component
public class InsertRestService extends RouteBuilder {

  

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        

        
        rest("/").produces("application.json")
        .get("selectPerson/{name}")//.outType(EmployeeInfo.class)
        .to("direct:selectPerson");

    from("direct:selectPerson")
        .transform().simple("SELECT * FROM person WHERE name=" + "'${header.name}'")
        .log("${body}")
        .to("jdbc:dataSource") //spring boot starter jdbc creates the bean in the registry
        .process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange xchg) throws Exception {
               //the camel jdbc select query has been executed. We get the list of employees.
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) xchg.getIn().getBody();
                        
                List<EmployeeInfo> employees = new ArrayList<EmployeeInfo>();
                System.out.println(dataList);
                for (HashMap<String, String> data : dataList) {
                    EmployeeInfo employee = new EmployeeInfo();
                    
                    employee.setEmpId(data.get("id"));
                    
                    employee.setEmpName(data.get("name"));
                    
                    employees.add(employee);
                    
                }
                xchg.getIn().setBody(employees)
                ;
            }
        
        })
        .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson)
        .log("${body}");
        
        
     
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Long and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

I think it is because of the hashmap `HashMap<String, String>` having the types string but I don t know how to do it since I have mixed types in hashMap.

Also I have a class:

```
public class EmployeeInfo {

    private String empId;
    private String empName;

    public String getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(String empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[empId=" + empId + ", empName=" + empName + "]";
    }

}
```

when trying to change the type of `empId` to ``long``` it does not work as well.

I would appreciate any help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Please add the complete stack trace of the exception to your question. 2. Why are you casting the result of `getBody()` to `(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>)`? 3. What do you mean by "when trying to change the type of empId to ``long``` it does not work as well."?

Comment: Assuming that `data.get("id")` returns a value of type *Long*. Then consider using `.toString()` for setting your id:
E.g:
`employee.setEmpId(data.get("id").toString());`

Comment: In order to be able to access the data returned by the query, I had to cast the result to ```(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>)``` and access the array using the ```for loop```. Answering your third question I tried to chnage ```private String empId;``` to ```private Long empId;```.

Comment: Adding ```to.String()``` to ```employee.setEmpId(data.get("id").toString());``` did not solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try converting

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>
```

to

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>
```

Post that based on your field name when you do data.get() you can type cast it to required type by instance checking.

Also, if you want to check types:
you can add a log before each field access

```
Object obj = data.get(<field>);
log(obj.getClass().getName());
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: what do you mean by "you can type cast it to required type by instance checking.", because converting to ```ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>``` is giving an error on ```setEmpId``` and ```setEmpName```: ```The method setEmpId(String) in the type EmployeeInfo is not applicable for the arguments (Object)```. Thank you!

Comment: Something like 

Object obj = data.get(<field>);
if (obj instanceof Long) {
// DO this;
}